# How do i fix error?? Error: expected ";" before "factorial"? it says in Line 16

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error and do not know how to fix it. My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int  factorial = 1, current = 2, n;
  cout << "enter number to calculate factorial of: ";
  cin >> n;

  while (current <= n){
    factorial = current * factorial;
    current++;
  }
  cout << n << "!= " factorial << endl;

  while (n < 0) {
    cout << "Must enter a positive number!\n";
    cout << "re-Enter number to calculate factorial of: ";
    cin >> n;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an operator:

```
cout << n << "!= " factorial << endl;
```

Should be:

```
cout << n << "!= " << factorial << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I looked it over and over and couldn't figure it out.  Program ran perfect!

Comment: Happy to help. In the future, it'd be a good idea to indicate which line of code is having problems. Put a comment in the code or something. You just said "line 16" so I had to count, and the line numbering didn't match up. :) Also, don't forget to accept the answer to let others know that your question has been resolved.

Comment: ok thanks for the heads up, this is my first time using this website.